# Is group theory and in general pure maths useful in applied mathematics?

Tags: group-theory, education

I've just finished the first year of Mathematics at University. I've already encountered groups, in a soft mini-course that took around half semester. 
My idea would be to study applied mathematics, even though I'm not entirely sure which particular field.

Next year I could study group theory, algebra and geometry. I thought these are all pretty abstract modules which wouldn't really benefit my applied-maths "curriculum". However I've been speaking to many students and lecturers and some of their answers where contradictory. Many thought that those courses are fundamental also for an applied mathematician and that it is better to specialize after graduation, maybe after the master even.

Do you think that those pure mathematics modules (and in general pure mathematics topics) are essential to an applied mathematician?

In which way could these topics improve the performance and the career of an applied mathematician?

Wouldn't be better just to specialize and study mathematical physics and statistics?

I'm not sure this is the right place for this question, however I'd like to hear your opinion of this.

Comment: One application that I've seen is the study of the symmetry groups of molecules. These are useful in spectrometry because transitions which are "too symmetric" cannot be triggered by interaction with light. Abstract algebra is also a major part of the Standard Model in particle physics.

Comment: @Ian , Thank you! Would you say that someone without a strong pure background would have a hard time excelling in applied mathematics?

Comment: Tough to say.  I was applied mathemetics in college -- Mathematical Economics.  Gerard Debreu, Bank of Sweden prize winner and one of the greatest mathematical economists of all times, was the instructor.  Anyway, one of Debreu's great contributions was to apply topological set theory to economics problems.  Topology is generally one of the "pure" topics.  My point, don't draw the pure / applied line to firmly.

Comment: @DougM, thank you for your comment! This is interesting, I didn't know topology actually had any applied application. As an applied mathematician, did you attend many pure modules? if yes, Are they helping you?

Comment: "Traditional" applied mathematics is pretty much all about deriving and analyzing differential equations. For that, abstract algebra is basically no use, and topology is of a relatively limited use. (Often all the topology you'll ever need as an analyst is taught in real analysis and functional analysis, rather than a separate topology class).

Comment: @Ian, if your aim was to be an applied mathematician and you had to pick two paths among these three: applied, statistics(and prob), pure.
Which couple would you chose to have higher chances of becoming a good applied mathematician?

Comment: The first two, in part because data work is still "applied math" work if not in the traditional sense.

Comment: @Ian, thank you a lot for your opinion! Those are actually the two paths I've chosen, however I still had doubts about them.